# Java String Date Validation Using Hibernate API

Tags: java, bean-validation

I am attempting to validate **String Date**  using `javax.validation` & Hibernate validation. i need to check given String date should be past and it should be correct `yyyyMMdd` format with all constraints like leap year, `30th`, `31st` day.

```
 public class UserInformation {

        @NotNull 
        public String idNum = null;

        @NotNull
        //@Past
        @Pattern(regexp="\\d{4}(1[012]|0[1-9])(3[01]|[12]\\d|0[0-9])")
        public String dob= null;

    }
```

I tried with this code but not working. Is there any solution. if we have custom validator then is it in field level.Please give suggestion or code snippet.

Comment: why don't you save as a date/timestamp/etc ?

Comment: My requirement is to accept as String..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Option 1

Change your pattern to this:

```
Pattern(regexp = "([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/[0-9]{4}")
```

But keep in mind that this kind of validation is not checking if February has less than 28/29 days, and other dates constraints.

### Options 2

Create your custom constraint validator

> Annotation

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = CheckDateValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface CheckDateFormat {

    String message() default "{message.key}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };

    String pattern();

}
```

> Validator class

Having the Date object you can do any other validation you want (like refuse dates in the past)

```
public class CheckDateValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CheckDateFormat, String> {

    private String pattern;

    @Override
    public void initialize(CheckDateFormat constraintAnnotation) {
        this.pattern = constraintAnnotation.pattern();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String object, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintContext) {
        if ( object == null ) {
            return true;
        }

        try {
            Date date = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).parse(object);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

> Use

```
@CheckDateFormat(pattern = "ddMMyyyy")
private String value;
```

Comment: Sorry to Ask this question. where to put @CheckDateFormat(pattern = "ddMMyyyy").. i cannot put like this.
@CheckDateFormat(pattern = "ddMMyyyy")
public String dob= null;
& What should be the values for FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER, ANNOTATION_TYPE.

Comment: FIELD, METHOD, etc are static values of ElementType, I made some edits

Comment: This one is not validating Feb 29 1987.. it returns true.. 
So i changed code as..
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( pattern );
            dateFormat.setLenient( false );
            try {
                dateFormat.parse(object);
                return true;
            } 
            catch (ParseException e) {
                return false;
            }
Now its working..

Comment: Its really helped me. Thank you so much dude.

Comment: I'm noob with regex, would you be able to explain what does [0-2][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/[0-9]{4} mean?

Comment: @kevenlolo that regex is not correct, you'll probably want something like this: ([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])\/[0-1][0-9]\/[0-9]{4}. I advice you to do some research on regex, https://regex101.com/ is a very useful site

Comment: This parse it wrongly when I add pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm" and value as "2022-23-23-04:00" it still sends true.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @Kedar9444. Interesting behaviour, you should set simpleDateFormat.setLenient(false) before parsing to deal with that. But at this point in time if you can use java 8 time api, you should give it a try: LocalDateTime.parse("2022-12-23-04:00", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm"))